# Why and how does jQuery's `$(this)` reference the right nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, internals

I know how to use jQuery's `$(this)` selector and I also understand the principles of OOP in Javascript. I always accepted that it just works, because somebody else implemented it, but I would love to know **why and how** it works.

```
$(function(){
   $('.foo').each(function(){
      console.log($(this));
   });
});
```

Given this code. I know that `$('.foo')` finds a set of HTML elements and returns a *jQuery object* which is able to iterate over them using `.each(...)`. The internal structure of the `each()` method then probably calls the closure, which has been passed as a parameter.

But why does `this` then reference the particular HTML element inside the closure? I always thought that `this` would only reference a new scope, as far as it's wrapper has been instantiated using `new`. So wouldn't it be much more consistent if `this` referenced `window` instead?

Comment: `this` is weird in javascript.  search the web and you'll find a bajillion blog posts from people explaining it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end you can always force a `this` value in a function using `.call` or `.apply`. jQuery does this; look at the [source of `.each`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L592):

```
if ( callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] ) === false ) {
//                  ^ `this` value
```

Here, the `this` value will be set to the element (`object[i]`), and the counter (`i`) and the element are passed as arguments to your function, which is `callback`.

Comment: I knew of the existence of `.call()` but I did not imagine to use it in combination with a parameter which is a HTML element. I couldn't have thought of a better answer, this explains it very well. Thank you!

Comment: @YMMD: It isn't in fact much different than anything else you can pass to `.call`. If you pass a variable that contains an element, the element will be the `this` value.

Answer (score 4):

It is a simple iterate of all matching elements with class `.foo` and call the inner function using `.call/.apply`.

Check the `.each` implementation http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.each

Note the .call/.apply call in the below code which make sure that `this` as `.foo[i]`

jQuery `.each` implementation

```
function (object, callback, args) {
    var name, i = 0,
        length = object.length,
        isObj = length === undefined || jQuery.isFunction(object);
    if (args) {
        if (isObj) {
            for (name in object) {
                if (callback.apply(object[name], args) === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (; i < length;) {
                if (callback.apply(object[i++], args) === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (isObj) {
            for (name in object) {
                if (callback.call(object[name], name, object[name]) === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (; i < length;) {
                if (callback.call(object[i], i, object[i++]) === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "why" is because that is how [`jQuery(selector).each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is *defined* to operate:

> ...the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, *so the keyword this refers to the element.*

It didn't need to be done this way, but it was. (See [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for the "how" mechanism used.)

Happy coding!

Comment: If it wasn't, then the only possibility would be to pass an argument to the callback which refers to the element, or is there another way? Thank you too for the quick answer!